# Dojo: click on the tab

Tags: dojo, tabs

I need to attach onClick event to tab, not to its content. For example, viewing the [example](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/layout/TabContainer.html#programmatic-example,), I want the event firing when I click "Drinks" tab.
The following code results in firing event when I click on tab's content, so it is *not* what I need:

```
        <div
            dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane"
            href="test.php"
            onClick="alert(1);"
        >
        </div>
```

Attaching event to tab container results in firing event when click both tabs and tab content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to connect to the event `onShow`.  Take a look at the "Event Summary" heading in the reference documentation:

http://dojotoolkit.org/api/dijit/layout/ContentPane

```
<div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" href="test.php" onShow="console.log('I'm being shown')"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, why didn't I scroll there :/

Answer (score -1):

maybe you can write a something like this :

dojo.connect(
    dojo.byId("myTab"),
    "onclick",
    function(){
        alert('click');
    }
);